# Search string to add line after specific word in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, search, save

*(I am a VERY basic programmer)*

I have a body of text which needs searching through to find a specific word "Customer" and then save the next line as the CustomerName (CustomerName = >line of text<)

Comment: You could show sample text and a desired result. Is there anything you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

If your "*body of text*" is a `TextBox` you could take profit of the `.Lines` property:

```
Dim index As Integer
Dim customerName As String = ""

For i As Integer = 1 to TextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
    If TextBox1.Lines(i-1).Contains("Customer") Then
        customerName =  TextBox1.Lines(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If you have a plain text, you can obtain the lines splitting the whole text:

```
Dim lines() As String = sAllText.Split(Environment.NewLine())
```

And then doing the same as before, but instead of using `TextBox1.Lines`, use `lines`.